# How to prevent code for adding an image to ShinyDashboard header appearing in browser tab?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have added code to display a logo in the header of a shinydashboard app I am working on. The image displays as I hoped but the code is appearing within the sheet tab of the internet browser which is obviously not ideal, is there a way to prevent this from happening?

[image: Example Image]

The relevant line of code I have used is:

```
dashboardHeader(title = tags$a(tags$img(src = "/MainLogo.png", align = "left")))
```

A full working example is given below (image file located in 'www' folder within the app project folder).

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = tags$a(tags$img(src = "/MainLogo.png", align = "left"))),

  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

      box(
        title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into the same issue before, I hope this works for you. I had to look back at a previous application, and this was under my sidebar environment in the ui.R, you may need to play around with where it is placed, but it should work.

`HTML('<script> document.title = "Internet Tab Name"; </script>')`

Comment: Thanks for looking, I also found an alternative solution which I have posted.

Answer (score 3):

After doing more searching I found one solution is to add the title you want in the browser tab to the dashboardPage section of the code e.g.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  title = "My Demo App",
```

So, the full code for the example is:

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  title = "My Demo App",
  dashboardHeader(title = tags$a(tags$img(src = "/MainLogo.png", align = "left"))),

  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

      box(
        title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be using JavaScript which can edit or modify title. So in order to insert JS script into Shiny app one could use `tags$head(tags$script(...))` which means JavaScript will only appear in the `<head>` of a document.

So the part below

```
  tags$head(tags$script(
          "  $(document).ready(function() {
            document.title = 'My Demo App';
        });"
        )),
```

can be inserted inside `dashboardBody()`.